# C# DataView Date Range with LIKE Operator?

Tags: c#, dataview, sql-like, date-range

I have an XML file:

```
<SMS>
    <Number>+447761692278</Number>
    <DateTime>2009-07-27T15:20:32</DateTime>
    <Message>Yes</Message>
    <FollowedUpBy>Unassigned</FollowedUpBy>
    <Outcome></Outcome>
    <Quantity>0</Quantity>
    <Points>0</Points>
  </SMS>
  <SMS>
    <Number>+447706583066</Number>
    <DateTime>2009-07-27T15:19:16</DateTime>
    <Message>STOP</Message>
    <FollowedUpBy>Unassigned</FollowedUpBy>
    <Outcome></Outcome>
    <Quantity>0</Quantity>
    <Points>0</Points>
  </SMS>
```

I use an XMLReader to read the file into a dataset and display it in a datagridview.
I want to be able to specify a range of dates to display the data for. For example where the   element contains a date between INSERT DATE & INSERT DATE.
In order to do this I am using a DATAVIEW and then populating the datagridview with the dataview instead of the dataset.

Currently I have a method as below:

```
public void DisplayRecSmsByDateRange(string date1,string date2, string readDir)
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet("SMS DataSet");
            XmlDataDocument xmlDatadoc = new XmlDataDocument();
            xmlDatadoc.DataSet.ReadXml(readDir);
            ds = xmlDatadoc.DataSet;

            DataView custDV = new DataView(ds.Tables["SMS"]);
            custDV.RowFilter = String.Format("(DateTime >= DateTime LIKE '{0}*' AND DateTime <= DateTime LIKE '{1}*')", EscapeLikeValue(date1), EscapeLikeValue(date2));
            this.dataGridView1.DataSource = custDV;
        }
```

The problem is that if you look at the xml file, the  element contains the time as well as the date. Since I am not interested in the time part of this element, I would use the "LIKE" statement to display the data from the xml file based on just the date part of the element. As a result of this, when i try and perform a boolean operation to say for example - "Show me the data for dates between 2009-07-27 and 2009-07-30", I get an error since the compiler does not like that I am trying to combine the LIKE operator with the boolean <=,>= operators (Shown in the above method). Is there a way around this? I need to be able to display data between a range of dates but use the LIKE operator to search based only the first part of the  element.

Help appreciated greatly,

Kind regards.

Comment: Let's hope those aren't real UK mobile phone numbers you've posted there.

Comment: Refer http://www.ilearnttoday.com/dataview-row-filter-for-date-time to use like operator for date column in dataview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slight alteration to the method, removing the LIKE operator worked......

```
public void DisplayRecSmsByDateRange(string date1,string date2, string readDir)
            {
                DataSet ds = new DataSet("SMS DataSet");
                XmlDataDocument xmlDatadoc = new XmlDataDocument();
                xmlDatadoc.DataSet.ReadXml(readDir);
                ds = xmlDatadoc.DataSet;

                DataView custDV = new DataView(ds.Tables["SMS"]);
                custDV.RowFilter = String.Format("(DateTime >= '{0}*' and DateTime <= '{1}*')", EscapeLikeValue(date1), EscapeLikeValue(date2));

                custDV.Sort = "DateTime";
                this.dataGridView1.DataSource = custDV;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that you can modify/replace the EscapeLikeValue() method so that it returns only date part, e.g. "2009-09-27". This way you can rewrite the filter to something like:

```
custDV.RowFilter = String.Format("(DateTime >= '{0}' AND DateTime <='{1}')", EscapeLikeValue(date1) + "T00:00:00", EscapeLikeValue(date2) + "T23:59:59");
```

HTH,
Dejan

Comment: That can't be correct though, because I want to be able to ignore the time value completely.....Hence the use of the LIKE operator. The code you have posted would simply amend a date onto the end, which isn't something that I want. I want to, for example, be able to display data that has a <DateTime> element value of say 2009-07-09. I don't care what the time part of that element contains. The LIKE operator takes care of this by allowing the compiler to "Not Care" and select only the start of the <DateTime> element value.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is to convert the date string parameters into actual datetime objects like so

```
 DateTime dt = System.Convert.ToDateTime(date1);
 DateTime dt2 = System.Convert.ToDateTime(date2);
 dt2=dt2.AddDays(1);
```

and then you can modify your where like so

```
custDV.RowFilter=String.Format("DateTime>={0} and DateTime<{1}",dt.ToShortDateString(),dt2.ToShortDateString());
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you can do the following:

```
custDV.RowFilter = String.Format("(Convert(DateTime,'System.DateTime' >= #{0}# AND Convert(DateTime,'System.DateTime' <= #{1}#)", EscapeLikeValue(date1), EscapeLikeValue(date2));
```